# Using DialogInterface's onClick() method

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Here is my code to initialize the `AlertDialog`; `buildexit` is `AlertDialog.Builder` and `exitalert` is `AlertDialog`:

```
buildexit=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
buildexit.setTitle("Exit?");
buildexit.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_warning);
buildexit.setMessage("Do you want to really exit?");
buildexit.setPositiveButton("Yes", this);
buildexit.setNegativeButton("No", this);
exitalert=buildexit.create();
```

I want to terminate the application using `Activity.finish()` method when the user clicks the "Yes" button, if "No" is click nothing should happen, I have also implemented the `android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener` interface, the method implemented is `public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

I know this is an old question, but if you are like me, and ended here because you where googling, this is probably what you are looking for.

To avoid creating a new `DialogInterface.onClickListener()` for each button, you can let the class implement `AlertDialog.OnClickListener`, and then override `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)`.

The `int which` in this method is the button that was clicked, or the position. See the [Android Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON1) for more detailed information.

So if you want to check which button was clicked you can use a switch-case and look for the constants `BUTTON_NEGATIVE`, `BUTTON_NEUTRAL`, and `BUTTON_POSITIVE`.

Example:

```
// skipping package and imports
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements AlertDialog.OnClickListener {

    void createAndShowDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.title);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.message);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, this);
        builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel, this);
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, this);
        builder.create().show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                // int which = -2
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
            case BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                // int which = -3
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
            case BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                // int which = -1
                TestActivity.this.finish();
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this out :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way that I implement the interface and use the onClick(...), like `public class ... extends Activity implements android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lambda to shorten your code. **JAVA**

```
AlertDialog.Builder buildexit = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
buildexit.create();
buildexit.setTitle("Exit?");
buildexit.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_warning);
buildexit.setMessage("Do you want to really exit?");
buildexit.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, id) -> 
{
    this.finish();
});
buildexit.setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, id) -> 
{
    //Leaving this empty will close this onClick
});
buildexit.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog buildexit = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Exit?")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setMessage("Do you want to really exit?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            MainActivity.this.finish();                
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();                
        }
    })
    .create();

    buildexit.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin and lambdas:

```
val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(atakContext)
alertDialog.setTitle("Error!")
alertDialog.setMessage("Please ")

alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog: DialogInterface?, whichButton: Int ->
    //Do something
}
alertDialog.show()
```